# Assume that G is of order 4 (not a cyclic group) find all its subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

I know that the cyclic group it contains at least one element that generates the group itself

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Do you know Lagrange's theorem? What can the orders of the non-identity elements be? If you are at an early stage of learning about Groups it is well worth doing this "hands-on" rather than finding slick answers from people who know more than you do. That way you will start to get a sense of how groups and their elements behave.

Answer (score 1):

The only noncyclic group of order 4 is the Klein-Four group $V = \{e,a,b,c\}$,
where $e$ is the unit element and $a^2=b^2=c^2=e$.

The nontrivial subgroups are $\{e,a\}$, $\{e,b\}$, and $\{e,c\}$.